# Codemagic doesn't detect codemagic.yaml file

Tags: cicd, codemagic

I have a small flutter project but I'm having an issue where codemagic is not detecting the codemagic.yaml file even thou I can see it in github and in my local folder,

It sounds silly but it's true

The file should be detected automatically

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are checking the same branch. Also double check that file name doesn't have any typos, all letters are latin and in lower case. The file extension also should be exact `.yaml` not `.yml`

Comment: Yep, checked that weeks ago, and it's merged in my dev branch

Comment: should be ok now, there was an incident recently you can read here https://github.com/orgs/codemagic-ci-cd/discussions/2107#discussioncomment-7260611